# Raspberry Windows 10 difference between external USB Stick and external Harddisc

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I wrote a foreground application in C# which collects images from different servers and stores them on SD card, USB stick, or disk.

In the application manifest, I set read/write filetypes and access to 
removable drives.

The application is working if I use a USB Stick to store data, or
if I use the system SD card.  But if I use an external HDD to store the data, the `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(DirName)` fails. Why?

The path is in both cases "E:\". In that Path I create sub directories,
where files should be created:

```
   public async void GetWebImage(String urlStr, String filename)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                String DirName  = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
                String FileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                // Folder Struktur erzeugen
                var rootFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(DirName);

                var http_file = await rootFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(urlStr);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                using (var stream = await http_file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await resStream.CopyToAsync(stream.AsStreamForWrite());
                }
                response.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)//any exceptions happend while saving the picture
            {
                String s = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String s = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The Path and storage to external drives I get this way :

```
// Get Path to first external Drive, otherwise "ExternalStorageFolder==null"
    public StorageFolder ExternalStorageFolder;
    private async void GetFirstExternalStoragePath()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder externalDevices;
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives;

            externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
            externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
            ExternalStorageFolder = externalDrives[0];

            TxtStatus.Text = "External Drive:"+ ExternalStorageFolder.Path + " found.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String s = "No external Drive found\n" + ex.ToString();

            TxtStatus.Text = s;
            ExternalStorageFolder = null;
        }
    }
```

If I access directly via "ExternalStorageFolder" I get no "access denied"
But if I use the "GetFolderFromPathAsync(DirName) this fails... Why?

Comment: Have you tried add some capabilities based on ["Retrieve a folder using: 
StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know waht you mean ? The problem is that StorageFolder.GetFolderfromPathAsync() fails..

Comment: I mean you can try to add some networks capabilities when access Universal Naming Convention (UNC) folders([Accessing additional locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations)).